# How to solve psycopg SyntaxError while executing "SHOW DATABASES LIKE" query?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I use Windows 11, Python 3.10.4 64-bit, PostgreSQL 14.2 database and psycopg2 2.9.3.

I connect to a database:

```
import psycopg2

SCHEMA_NAME = "myschema"

connx = psycopg2.connect(database="mydatabase", user="myadmin", password="123456", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432", options="-c search_path=myschema")

cur = connx.cursor()
```

Then I want to check if the schema exists:

```
sql_str = "SHOW DATABASES LIKE %s ESCAPE ''"
cur.execute(sql_str, [SCHEMA_NAME])
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    cur.execute("SHOW `DATABASES` LIKE %s ESCAPE ''", [SCHEMA_NAME])
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "LIKE"
LINE 1: SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'myschema' ESCAPE ''
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Why do you have backwards quotes around DATABASES?

Comment: There is no `SHOW DATABASES` command in Postgres SQL

Comment: Where [in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html) did you find the `show databases` command ?

Comment: @wildplasser What do you mean? Isn't SQL language universal? It works fine with MySQL.

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry, actually I don't have backwards quotes, i corrected the question.

Comment: @johncryer no, SQL is not universal. Every database has its own dialect unfortunately.

Comment: _Isn't SQL language universal?_ Oh, you sweet summer child...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL a **schema** and a **database** are 2 different things.

The following query will tell you whether the schema exists.

```
SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'myschema';
```

And your code becomes

```
sql_str = "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name =  %s ;"
cur.execute(sql_str, [SCHEMA_NAME])
```

If you are checking that a database exists it will be

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname='dbname';
```

And your code will become

```
sql_str = "SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname =  %s ;"
cur.execute(sql_str, [DATABASE_NAME])
```

Comment: 1) This works for finding schemas, but the OP is looking for databases. 2) This probably works in MySQL(where schema=database), but the OP is using Postgres where a `schema` and a `database` are two different things. Either update the answer to match Postgres reality or delete it.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The question says **I connect to a database:   ...   Then I want to check if the schema exists:**

Comment: And the command they are using is `sql_str = "SHOW DATABASES LIKE %s ESCAPE ''"` From here [SHOW DATABASES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html)  this is a  synonym for `SHOW SCHEMA`. The problem is that this is only the case for MySQL and the OP is working on Postgres. Your answer will not provide the correct result in Postgres.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I agree that it's not clear. I've given both options in my answer.